# Branching and Tagging SVN

Tags: svn, tags, branch

I have this school maintenance course and we had to mingle with SVN quite a lot. I've recently created a branch for some major refactoring(switched to that branch too). When I was done and went on to tag the branch,instead it auto-committed what I had in my branch to the trunk and tagged this final result(The trunk + changes of the branch).

I don't understand what went wrong, I thought that if I tagged my branch I would just get either a copy of the branch or of the trunk's current revision. Instead I had my branch auto-merged with my changes and then a tag was created of that revision.

Just wondering if someone can relate to what might ave been the issue, I'm just trying to figure out exactly what happened or if I used SVN the wrong way.

I've used tortoiseSVN to do so, here are somewhat the steps I did:

- Create a branch of current trunk into /branches with a switch to this branch
- Make changes to the code in my branch
- Create a tag of the trunk(Then it committed my branch into the trunk and then tagged).

Comment: SVN has no native concept of tags, so you must have used some 3rd-party tool.  Which one?

Comment: I used the GUI tortoise. I'll clarify the gui steps.

Comment: There's no way that TortoiseSVN auto-merges a branch into a trunk when you create a tag of the trunk. You've made something else.

Comment: In Subversion, you usually create a tag by copying the tree in question to the `tags` directory. This is pretty straight forward, and usually doesn't result in merging a branch to trunk. Can you find out the software you're using that did this? What platform are you on?

Comment: I am on Windows 7 and I've installed Tortoise SVN as a graphic toolkit that is incorporated into the context menu of the file explorer. I have to make another attempt that is similar soon, so hopefully I will see if this behavior was just a fluke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still there is some confusion about what you actually told TortoiseSVN to do.

I find it likely you copied your branch to the /trunk directory instead of the /tags directory -> your /trunk now is identical to your branch. This can be rectified with a reverse merge of that particular revision, and commit.

Generally, the log will tell you what happened. Can you post something from the log?

Comment: I'll accept your answer, the log doesn't seem to show off any odd behavior, the tag was created and there was a submission off the trunk before that. I've played with SVN a bit more and things have been mostly flawless. I think our SVN server might be the responsible, it's kind of unstable.